# Crawling custom application pages

Tags: search, crawling

I have a custom application page with some static text e.g. `_layouts/CustomAppPage.aspx` but it does not show in search results and crawl index.

I have tried all 3 approaches below (one by one) and failed:

1. Linking the page from a built-in wiki page
2. Created a crawl rule to include this portal, when I try to test the rules with `http://portal/_layouts/CustomAppPage.aspx` it marks the correct inclusion rule
3. Modified crawl rule to crawl entire portal as a web page (Added `http://portal/*` and set it to **Include** and **Crawl SharePoint content as http pages**)

All the other pages are being crawled. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Hi Tony, could you give a bit more info on step three - did you remove the custom app page in the crawl rule at this point?

Comment: Nope, added http://portal/* and set it to INCLUDE and crawl as web page

Comment: For the include rule it's usually http : // portal /* <-remove the spaces...but when you set up the rule is the Crawl Configuration set as HTTP or include all items in the path?

Comment: Uncheck the HTTP and make sure the default access account has permissions to the page, although it should if you have just added it.  I've seen weird results with the HTTP and you shouldn't need it if you are crawling your repository as an SP Site.

Comment: Tried that before enabling that. It did not work... The account should have privileges as this is IW Demo machine where all services run as CONTOSO\administrator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Toni, application pages are not crawled by the crawler when SharePoint is crawled. The crawler uses the SiteData.asmx/GetContent to find content to crawl for a web application. Since application pages are not a part of the actual content they are not being discovered.

If you want to crawl application pages you need to set up a standard web crawl content source and feed it with a root where it can disover the application page via a link or directly hitting your page.

If it's static text, why can't you add it to a Library (just as a Web Part Page)?

Comment: WOW, this really great. Implemented as suggested and now it is being crawled but still does not show in Search results but I will make further test. I do not plan to host just static text here so that's why I cannot deploy it as web part page, but maybe I could custom code as web part and serve it from Web Part Page hm....